# Needed to create a function thet recieves an array of 2 degits nums , Switch between the digits and print but got an error

Tags: java, arrays, function, integer, java.util.scanner

Write a function that receives double-digit numbers, until a number that is not double-digit is received.
• For each number received the program will generate a reverse number and print it. For example :  67 will be printed 76.
• The program will print a count of some of the received numbers thet contains the digit 5 ​​in the digit
Unity (right digit).

I researched the error I got a couple of times but couldn't solve it, if you guys can help much appreciated.

```
public static void switchInput() {
Scanner star = new Scanner(System.in);
int x=0 , temp=0  , y=1 , i , b=0;
x= star.nextInt();
int[] Switch = new int[x];
//input
for(i=0 ; i<y ; i++){
System.out.println("insert num "+ y + " :");
temp= star.nextInt();
x++;
y++;
Switch[i]=temp;
if(temp<10||temp>99) {
    y=i;
}
if(temp%10==5) {
    b++;
}
temp=0;
}
star.close();
//Switch
int j , temp2 , temp3=0;
for(j=0 ; j<x ; j++) {
temp3=Switch[j]/10;
temp2=Switch[j]%10;
temp3+=temp2*10;
Switch[j]=0;
Switch[j]=temp3;
}
 //print
for(int z = 0;z<x-1;z++) {
System.out.print(" "+Switch[z]+ " ");
} 
System.out.println("Number of times 5 was used is : " + b);
}
```

I got the error :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 44 out of bounds for length 44
at hagashaShadi.q1.switchInput(q1.java:37)
at hagashaShadi.q1.main(q1.java:67)

Answer (score 0):

See `x= star.nextInt();` here your providing size of array suppose its **x=3**
which means `int[] Switch = new int[3];`  but when you are running for loop you are getting like this Switch[4] which is out of bound for the array of size **3**. So solution is to use either while loop and insert only when it satisfy the condition and it should break once it cross size of array or if you want to use for loop then break out of loop when **i>length-of-array**

Have a look at the below code for more understanding

```
    public static void switchInput() {
        Scanner star = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i=0 , countDigit=0;
        List<Integer> numList=new ArrayList<>();
        boolean isTwoDigitNumber=true;
        //Insert all input number of 2 digit
        while(isTwoDigitNumber)
        {
            System.out.println("insert num "+ (i+1)+ " :");
            int temp= star.nextInt();
            if(temp%10==5){
                countDigit++;
            }
            if(temp>10&&temp<99) {
                numList.add(temp);
                i++;
            }else {
                isTwoDigitNumber=false;
            }
        }

        star.close();
//Switch
        //reverse the number and print
        for(int j=0 ; j<numList.size() ; j++) {
            int num = numList.get(j), reversed = 0;
            //System.out.println("Original Number: " + num);
            // run loop until num becomes 0
            while(num != 0) {

                // get last digit from num
                int digit = num % 10;
                reversed = reversed * 10 + digit;

                // remove the last digit from num
                num /= 10;
            }
            System.out.println("reverse Number: " + reversed);
        }
        //print number of times 5
        System.out.println("Number of times 5 was used is : "+countDigit);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't decide the length of the array head-on because I need to insert 2 digits numbers until the user inputs 1 digit or above 2 digits nums

Comment: int[] Switch = new int[x]; this tells you know the size. if you don't know the size better to use ArrayList

Comment: code edited kindly see it again .it will run till you get the non two digit number

Comment: Thanks a lot, never used Arraylist before so  I am not sure exactly what you did but ill research this.